# Function like plt.tight_layout() that changes figure size instead of axis size

Tags: python, matplotlib

`plt.tight_layout()` works by changing the axis size, so all elements in your figure fit within that figure frame.

See:

```
y=np.random.normal(size=100)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(); plt.plot(y)
plt.xlabel('time / s.', fontsize=40)
fig.set_size_inches([5, 2])
plt.tight_layout()
```

The axis got resized so all elements could fit in the figure. I want my axis size to remain constant. Is there an alternative that resizes the figure while leaving the axis untouched?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sizes of the axes are specified in terms of figure coordinates. I.e. by default a single subplot is 77.5% of the figure width wide and 77% of the figure height high. So you cannot leave the axes untouched when changing the figure size, because the one depends on the other.

Now it depends on the goal of calling `tight_layout` and the desired output.

#### The problem

Running the code from the question results in the following figure,

[image]

As can be seen, the oversized xlabel is cut.

### Saving the figure

If for example you are interested in saving your figure, you may do so without calling `tight_layout()` and instead specify the `bbox_inches="tight"` in the call to savefig.

```
plt.savefig("some.png", bbox_inches="tight")
```

This will produce a figure which is larger than the original one without changing any of the positions of the objects inside. It's hence different from `tight_layout` because it does not change the layout and spacings at all. The drawback here is that it will only affect the saved figure, not the one shown on screen.

### Showing the figure

Now you can in principle do the same to your figure which is on screen. This is very hacky and will have consequences on how your axes are stored. The following is a function `tight_figure`, which treats the figure as if it was saved, but lets it stay within the original canvas on screen.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import io
from matplotlib.transforms import Bbox, TransformedBbox, Affine2D
from matplotlib import  tight_bbox

def tight_figure(fig,**kwargs):
    canvas = fig.canvas._get_output_canvas("png")
    print_method = getattr(canvas, 'print_png')
    print_method(io.BytesIO(), dpi=fig.dpi,
                 facecolor=fig.get_facecolor(), dryrun=True)
    renderer = fig._cachedRenderer
    bbox_inches = fig.get_tightbbox(renderer)


    bbox_artists = fig.get_default_bbox_extra_artists()

    bbox_filtered = []
    for a in bbox_artists:
        bbox = a.get_window_extent(renderer)
        if a.get_clip_on():
            clip_box = a.get_clip_box()
            if clip_box is not None:
                bbox = Bbox.intersection(bbox, clip_box)
            clip_path = a.get_clip_path()
            if clip_path is not None and bbox is not None:
                clip_path = \
                    clip_path.get_fully_transformed_path()
                bbox = Bbox.intersection(
                    bbox, clip_path.get_extents())
        if bbox is not None and (
                bbox.width != 0 or bbox.height != 0):
            bbox_filtered.append(bbox)

    if bbox_filtered:
        _bbox = Bbox.union(bbox_filtered)
        trans = Affine2D().scale(1.0 / fig.dpi)
        bbox_extra = TransformedBbox(_bbox, trans)
        bbox_inches = Bbox.union([bbox_inches, bbox_extra])

    pad = kwargs.pop("pad_inches", None)
    if pad is None:
        pad = plt.rcParams['savefig.pad_inches']

    bbox_inches = bbox_inches.padded(pad)

    tight_bbox.adjust_bbox(fig, bbox_inches, canvas.fixed_dpi)

    w = bbox_inches.x1 - bbox_inches.x0
    h = bbox_inches.y1 - bbox_inches.y0
    fig.set_size_inches(w,h)


y=np.random.normal(size=100)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(); plt.plot(y)
plt.xlabel('time / s.', fontsize=40)
fig.set_size_inches([5, 2])

tight_figure(fig)

plt.show()
```

The output **with** `tight_figure` would look like
[image]

Comment: The option bbox_inches='tight' solves mot of my problems.
The hack tight_figure works well and lets you see the figure on screen, but has some odd behaviour when trying to save at different dpi.

Comment: Yes that is expected, because it determines the bounding box for the currently used dpi. If you need to save the figure, **first** save it with the option `bbox_inches='tight'`, only **after** that call this custom method.

Comment: `bbox_inches="tight"` is *the* thing! The thing which saved my day!